# How to set up free SSL certificate for my site running on google cloud plateform. (Windows 10)

Tags: django, windows, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I have hosted my website on google cloud platform on a windows server(newbie). Buyed domain from godaddy. I have no idea how to put SSL certificate for my site running on 0.0.0.0:80 port. 
Its simple django webapp.
Any one can help? Please.

I have tried using but didn't work
'''
pip install django-extensions
pip install Werkzeug
pip install pyOpenSSL
'''

Comment: Let's Encrypt is the usual answer. Integration with Windows is available via third parties.

Comment: If you don't have a specific reason for a Windows server, your life will be much simpler if you use a  UNIX-like operating system (linux).

Comment: Do you have a load balancer in front of your server?

Comment: @Richard on certbot My HTTP website is running

on ? what should I select?